# ES6 and angular using Factory from a separate file for a controller

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-class, es6-modules

using ES6 in my controller MyController I make an http request to retrieve a webapi json data.. works perfectly fine until..

I want to take this call and put it inside a service or a factory file outside of this controller file. I am not able to do so.. can someone guide me with this?

I have an app file that imports my controllers and other components like this

```
    import "babel-polyfill";
    import myController from "controllers";
    import myFactory from "factories";
    (function() {
     'use strict';
     config().ready.then(app => {
          app.mod       
         .factory('myFactory', myFactory).controller('my ....
```

I tried to create a factory like so:

```
export default class myFactory{
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }
    myData() {

        $http.get("/source").success(function(data) {
            vm.myData = data;
            vm.view.dataTable = data
        }).error(...);
    }
}
```

from my controller I tried calling it:

```
 import myFactory from "factory";
 export default class myController{
    constructor($http, $mdDialog, $mdToast) {
    let getMyData = new myFactory;
    getMyData.myData();
    var vm = this;
    vm.myJsonDataFromFactory ..... 
 }
```

I tried to import the class to my app and then to my controller file.. none worked.

error at this point is: Error: _factory.myFactory is not a constructor

Comment: Please, post controller code, not just a piece. And cite exact error messages, not just 'none worked'. Though it is obvious that the problem is that `myFactory` isn't an Angular service. There's no way how the  `myFactory` can figure out what `$http` should be injected there. With ES6 you still have to define services (for ES6 class a `service` service) and inject them as usual in controller.

Comment: @estus ..  in trying to make it work I have gotten various errors, but this is the error I get when I run that above code. See update of the question.

Comment: Thanks. Any way, the comment above is still relevant. If you're intending to use dependencies in the class ($http), make it a service and inject it into controller like usual. ES6 makes easier to handle some OOP patterns, but it isn't a replacement for Angular modules and services.

Comment: @estus I am new to ES6 so bare with me..but  I know it is not a replacement for the services and factory... I did try to inject them into the app section as factory and/service .. it just didn't work .. I am not sure if there is something I am missing in ES6 that I need to add ... do you know where I could look for examples? When I call my http from my controller directly everything works just fine.

Comment: Here's a question with example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155345/registering-angularjs-service-with-es6-syntax . ES6 doesn't differ from ES5 in fundamental things. `myFactory` (btw, it is not a factory at all, it is a constructor!) is a function (classes are functions with sugar syntax). It should be registered as `someModule.service('myFactory', myFactory)` and injected into controller the same way as you would do in ES5. You can always refer to transpiled code to be certain what's going on there.

Comment: @estus  see the update on my module .. I had it that way .. and I thought it should have  done the trick ...

Comment: Again, a constructor should be `service`, not `factory`. And you don't have to instantiate it with `getMyData = new myFactory`. Inject it like any other dependency in controller's constructor. But it doesn't explain `Error: _factory.myFactory is not a constructor`. Please, debug what exactly you import. It is `import myFactory from "factories"` in one place and `import myFactory from "factory"` in another. The problem is too broad because it depends on how the things are organized on your side.